# Populating a panel with selected items from a grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, datatemplate

I have a `DataGrid` with a bunch of rows representing items in my system. I want that each time a user selects an item in the grid (the user is allowed to select multiple items) the item will be added to a `StackPanel` and have its own datatemplate using an `Expander` to display its data.

Can anyone help me do this in WPF?

Thanks!
John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a StackPanel, but an ItemsControl, and bind its ItemsSource to the DataGrid's SelectedItems. However, at the moment I'm not sure whether SelectedItems has change notification. If not, you might have to use a CollectionViewSource in between, and call CollectionViewSource.Refresh during the DataGrid.SelectionChanged event.